# Sistema de classificação

Tags: php, html

Gostaria de fazer que aparecessem as posições.
Eu não tenho ideia de como fazer. Abaixo estarei dando uma demonstração e meu código

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
    <?php
   include("./configs/dados.php");
$ranking = "SELECT * FROM usuarios ORDER BY pontos_total  Desc LIMIT 3,10";
$limiteranking = mysql_query("$ranking");
while ($ranking = mysql_fetch_array($limiteranking)) {  
$nomeran = $ranking['login'];
$pontosran = $ranking['pontos_total'];
?>      




    <tr style="background:#d3a298">
      <th scope="row"><center>4º</th></center>
      <td style="color:#383838"><?php echo $nomeran; ?></td>
      <td style="color:#383838"><?php echo $pontosran; ?></td>
    </tr>

<?php } ?>
```

*Código apenas do 4º para baixo.
Como podem ver, gostaria que aparecesse 4º , 5º , 6º

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça assim:

```
<?php
include("./configs/dados.php");
$posicao = 4;
$ranking = "SELECT * FROM usuarios ORDER BY pontos_total  Desc LIMIT 3,10";
$limiteranking = mysql_query("$ranking");
while ($ranking = mysql_fetch_array($limiteranking)) {  
$nomeran = $ranking['login'];
$pontosran = $ranking['pontos_total'];
?>      




    <tr style="background:#d3a298">
      <th scope="row"><center><?php echo $posicao;?>º</th></center>
      <td style="color:#383838"><?php echo $nomeran; ?></td>
      <td style="color:#383838"><?php echo $pontosran; ?></td>
    </tr>

<?php $posicao++; } ?>
```

Explicando o código:

Ele cria uma váriavel com o valor de **4** que é a primeira posição. Sempre que ele fazer um novo loop, ou seja, quando pegar um novo registro ele acrescenta +1 assim sempre deixando a posição atual do usuário no ranking.

Obs: Caso queira que apareça como 1º, 2º, 3º... Altere o `$posicao = 4;` para `$posicao = 1;`

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente amigo. Mas uma dúvida: o $posicao++ significa que ele vai somar 1 qnd fizer o loop?

Comment: @VME Sim. Toda vez que fazer um loop, ou seja, listar mais um usuário no ranking, ele adiciona +1 no $posicao, assim ficando dinamico.

Answer (score 2):

Crie uma variável `$i` fora do laço armazenando quantas vezes o bloco foi iterado (repetido). A cada iteração, você acrescenta uma unidade a essa variável:

```
<?php
    include("./configs/dados.php");
    $ranking = "SELECT * FROM usuarios ORDER BY pontos_total  Desc LIMIT 3,10";
    $limiteranking = mysql_query("$ranking");

    $i = 0;
    while ($ranking = mysql_fetch_array($limiteranking)) {  
        $i = $i + 1;

        $nomeran = $ranking['login'];
        $pontosran = $ranking['pontos_total'];
?>      

        <tr style="background:#d3a298">
          <th scope="row"><center><?php echo $i; ?>º</th></center>
          <td style="color:#383838"><?php echo $nomeran; ?></td>
          <td style="color:#383838"><?php echo $pontosran; ?></td>
        </tr>

<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Funcionou também. Foi simples e não tinha pensado. Obrigado